# Is comparing feats from characters from different animes on topic in Anime SE?

Tags: discussion

I found this page which compares feats of fighting characters from different animes based on data from the series.

[Top Strongest](https://topstrongest.fandom.com/wiki/All-Might)

I wonder if this kind of questions are on topic here, since they can be seen as opinion-based. In one hand, I think they can be seen as opinion based since they compare feats of characters written by different authors, so no word from an author can determine if what it's said it's true or not. In the other hand, they use data based on events which happened in the anime or statements from the characters, which if they wouldnt be contradicted by the series itself, they would be objetive. (For example a minimun bar for All Might speed is calculated based in the time it's said he took to run 5 kms)

Are these kind of questions on topic here?

Pros: This kind of topics are very popular among anime fans
Cons: Hard not to get opinion based answers to this kind of questions.